# creating a horizontal menu in social engine php

Tags: socialengine

I have created a menu and inserted the generic menu widget onto a newly created page. I think by default it gives a verticle menu. I have tried various css codes found on the web to change it to a horizontal menu, but upon saving and refreshing the page I am not seeing any changes.

Can anyone advise me as to how I enable my generic menu to display the navigation links horizontally instead of vertically?

If I delete the menu and insert an html widget with code and links for a horizontal menu, other items such as my mini menu and footer menu display differently.

Thank you for your time

Regards

Amanda

Comment: Do that and keep us updating !!!

Comment: Hi, sorry what are you suggesting that i do?